# Using '*' in SQL FROM statement to access Excel cell range

Tags: c#, sql, excel, ssis, oledb

I have a script that converts an *.xlsx* file to *.csv* file but this script uses a cell range in Excel to read the data. The script is working but I wish to expand it to prevent possible user-bugs.

The query to select a Excel cell range (in **SQL**):

```
  string query = "SELECT * FROM fileName";
```

What I'm trying to do is make the script select an 'ALL' kind of range so that if a user changes the filename it still works. Like this:

```
  string query = "SELECT * FROM User_*";
```

`User_` will be standard for every document but what comes after the `_` can be changed by the users. Using `*` is not accepted as ALL in this case, and I can't seem to find something that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used another script to run an Excel macro on the document before converting it. This macro changed the name of the cell range to a common name that is now used to convert the document.